# Validation on selectOneMenu to display message in a SPAN

Tags: jsf, message

I have a drop down box in a JSF 1.2 web application:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value=“#{value}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please select a value.">
  <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel=“Please Select" />
  <f:selectItem itemValue=“1" itemLabel=“£1" />
  <f:selectItem itemValue=“2" itemLabel=“£2" />
  <f:selectItem itemValue=“3" itemLabel=“£3" />
  <f:selectItem itemValue=“4" itemLabel=“£4" />
  <f:selectItem itemValue=“5" itemLabel=“£5" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:messages/>
```

Which when a value is not selected, the message **Please select a value** is displayed.

However, is message is displayed in a `<ul>` `<li>`. How can i display this message in a `<span>`

Comment: Why do you need it to be displayed in a span? Can't you just use css to style things if needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's indeed the [default output](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/messages.html) of a `<h:messages>`.

Just use [`<h:message>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/message.html) instead of `<h:messages>` if you intend to display a single message instead of a list of messages (click the links, you'll see that it clearly describes how they are encoded to HTML).

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="foo" ... />
<h:message for="foo" />
```

Note that the `for` attribute must refer the (relative) client ID of the target component you'd like to display the message for.